# Problem: Ssh with ngrok tunneling using public key authentification?

Tags: ssh, public-key, ngrok

I want to connect to my home Ubuntu server from everywhere without port forwarding, so I decided to use ngrok tunneling. Usually I can log in to my server using ssh public key without any problem, but when I try it with ngrok I can connect to my ssh port on server but I get "*Permission denied (publickey)"* error. I check the internet for possible solutions which I believed at first there is definitely one, but unfortunately couldn't find any. They logged in to their servers using ssh passwords which I find it an insecure method to log in.

Here is when I tried to log in with ngrok:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/semih/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:7JQi7w9zU4/bm8jljhiw/DnQ7tHUZhNBAZj6juMdjFI agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

And here is a usual local auth. using public key:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/semih/.ssh/id_rsa RSA            
SHA256:7JQi7w9zU4/bm8jljhiw/DnQ7tHUZhNBAZj6juMdjFI agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/semih/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:7JQi7w9zU4/bm8jljhiw/DnQ7tHUZhNBAZj6juMdjFI agent
Authenticated to localip(localip:port) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow so don't hesitate to criticise and feedback the way I describe the problem. I am looking for answers that can guide me to detect the problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: PM from ngrok here. Can you add in the commands you are using to start ngrok? I use `ngrok tcp 22` pretty frequently and have no issues with using passwordless ssh to my local servers. Our TCP tunnels are just byte for byte copies of the traffic flowing through them, so this sounds like a configuration issue between your ssh client and server where it isn't presenting the correct certificate.

Comment: I was using a port other than 22, now I tried 22 and nothing changed.
my lines are:
On the server side:
     ./ngrok tcp [portnumber]
On pc I want to connect:
      ssh 8.tcp.ngrok.io -v -p [givenportnumberfromgrok]

Comment: I deleted ssh on my server, an reinstalled then the problem was solved. It turns out that I did something to sshd_config that i didn't supposed to do, but I don't know what was wrong.